# Why the plot is linear when i am plotting an exponential function

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I expect a curve cause of using exponential function but i get linear plot...
why this happens?
I am just going to plot values of V and i expect to be an exponential curve not linear

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

I=[1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]
V=np.zeros(10)
counter=0

def eps(s):
    return (s/1.5)*np.exp(1-(s/1.5))

for t in range(10):
    _I= I[:t+1]    
    for counter in range(t+1):
        if _I[counter]==1:
            t_f=counter
            s=t- t_f
            V[t]+=eps(s)
        if V[t]>3:
            V[t-1]=4
            V[t]=-0.065
    print('V[t] in t=',t,'is=',V[t])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(V)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you check the scales - do they have logarithmic scaling such that the plot only _looks_ linear but is in fact exponential?

Comment: Thanks @ jbndlr for your response .... but i did not catch you...what u mean by looks linear but in fact exponential..plus when i am using an exponential function...just it should be a exponential curve ...

Comment: An exponential function on a logarithmic axis plots as a straight line.